# Can't pass variables to CGI with POST method

Tags: php, http-post, cgi

To test things out I did this .sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
export REQUEST_METHOD=POST 
export SCRIPT_FILENAME=/www2/post_example.php 
export CONTENT_LENGTH=12
export REDIRECT_STATUS=true
export username=bob
exec echo 'username=bob' | /usr/bin/php-cgi7.0 -e
```

The php that I am using to test is the following:

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['username'];
?>
```

And whenever I try to run the script it says:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /www2/post_example.php on line 2
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>/www2/post_example.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

I don't know what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I missed the Content-Type header.

```
CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```